# Mysql count slow when filter by category

Tags: php, mysql

Why my query fast when I run.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `news` where `news`.`deleted_at` is null and `status` = '1'
```

But, slow when I run.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `news` where `news`.`deleted_at` is null and `status` = '1' and `newscategory_id` = '17'
```

It is my table `news` structure image, have a look at [here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10960239_948706481806728_2383314817827746778_o.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9).

**Sorry because my reputation is less than 8, so I can't attach image.**

Comment: how long is the difference between both of them?

Comment: With `newscategory_id` can more than 30 second but without `newscategory_id` can less than 1 second

Comment: Is newscategory_id not an int?

Comment: Yes its INT , you can view the structur at this : https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10960239_948706481806728_2383314817827746778_o.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9

Comment: Sorry, missed the link the first time reading.

Comment: so what do you think chris ?

Comment: How much cathegories in that table? In your example is `17`. Another else? Do you think the same with me right now?

Comment: how if without quote (')? '1' ==> 1, '17' ==> 17

Comment: there are 91 record , but in this case , i want to show news per category

Comment: I was thinking that newscategory_id was/is being interrupted as a string not an int. With 91 records though that shouldn't be taking 30 seconds. You tagged this with php as well, what driver is this being processed with (pdo, mysql, mysqli)? Do you experience the same behavior when executing it direct on the server?

Comment: chris , i use laravel 4.2,and laravel use PDO

Comment: crhis , i tested with navicat , the query more slow than i tested with laravel

Comment: @MuhamadAlfisyahRezaDaulay: did you try changing the query as mentioned by andi sholihin?

Comment: @olli , it doesn't give significant different , but i dont know why if i had open the newscategory page and open same again query is fast.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an composite index on the three columns you are using for your select:

```
ALTER TABLE news ADD INDEX comp_index (deleted_at, status, newscategory_id);
```

and check it again.
probably use EXPLAIN to see if any indexes you have are used.

Comment: still slow , it's the result https://scontent-b-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/10986865_948715651805811_6442072898118789220_o.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9

Comment: could you please show the extra column from the explain in full?

Comment: yes, it is Using intersect(news_status_index,news_newscategory_id_foreign,news_deleted_at_index); Using where; Using index

Answer (score 0):

> Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly.
>   Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read
>   through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the
>   table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns
>   in question, MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in
>   the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data.
>   This is much faster than reading every row sequentially.

Try to add this in your DB:

```
CREATE INDEX newCategory_indx ON news (newscategory_id)
CREATE INDEX status_indx ON news (status)
```

This will give you quick result, as compared to previously generate (non-indexed column) result.

To know more about index and it's importance [visit here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: So, instead of adding quotes on the numbers like status = '1' use status = 1 instead. see if that helps. Can you tell me what is your table size?

Comment: news table has 103965 record .

Comment: That's a hell lot of entries

Comment: i thinks it's not big

Comment: Try implementing view for that, it might help.

Comment: what do you mean about view ?

Comment: Try creating view for your table, it might be efficient.

Comment: what do you have an example to implement this ?

Comment: Visit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm. creating view is still not a good solution but you can try for change

Comment: i think view is not best solution